# Nested Quantifiers (And vs Implies)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I would like to understand something regarding the nested quantifiers in discrete math.
In the following question part (c):

> Let $M(x,y)$ be "$x$ has sent $y$ an e-mail message", and $T(x,y)$ be "$x$ has telephoned $y$", where the domains consist of all students in your class. Use quantifiers to express each of the following statements. (Assume that all e-mail messages that were sent are received.)
>
> (c) There is a student in your class who has sent everyone else in your class an e-mail message.

Is this answer correct:

$$\exists x\,\forall y\,[(x\ne y)\to M(x,y)]$$

And if yes, why to use the implication although it's gonna result in True if the $x = y$ and the student has sent himself an email (Which should be False not True).

Also when should we use and ($\land$) and not $\to$?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\exists x\,\forall y\,[(x\ne y)\to M(x,y)]$ correctly translates *There is a student in your class who has sent everyone else in your class an e-mail message*. The italicized statement does not say whether this student has sent himself an e-mail: provided that the student has sent everyone else in the class an e-mail, the statement is true both if he has sent himself an e-mail as well and if he has not done so.

And that’s exactly what the formal version says: $(x\ne y)\to M(x,y)$ is true if $x=y$ both when $M(x,y)$ is true — i.e., when $x$ *has* sent himself an e-mail — and when $M(x,y)$ is false — i.e., when $x$ has *not* sent himself an e-mail.

Your last question is too broad for me to be able to give you a useful answer.

Comment: If we don't need to consider whether he has sent himself an email or not, then ∃x∀y[M(x,y)] is enough. [Correct me if I am wrong.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020173/308385)

Comment: @jblixr: But we do need to consider whether he has sent himself an email: the original statement does not specify whether he has done so, so the formal translation also must not specify. $\exists x\,\forall y,\big(M(x,y)\big)$, unlike the original statement, says that he definitely *did* send himself an email, so it cannot be a correct translation. Mauro’s comment under your question correctly identifies one error in your answer there. The other even bigger error is that your version implies that there is a student who is not equal to himself.

Comment: Perfectly understood, thanks :) $\exists x \forall y[x \not = y \iff M(x, y)]$, Is this correct for "There is a student in your class who has sent everyone else but not him an e-mail message"?

Comment: @jblixr: It is indeed. You’re welcome.