# Nested Quantifiers Implications or Logical And?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let **M(x, y) :** "x has sent y an e-mail message"

where the domain consists of all students in your class.

**Question:** There is a student in your class who has sent everyone
else in your class an e-mail message

**My answer :** $\exists x \forall y[x \not =y\land M(x, y)]$

**Book answer:** $\exists x \forall y[x \not =y\implies M(x, y)]$

Why is my answer wrong and why is the book answer correct?

Comment: Because if the student $x$ is the only student of the class, clearly $x \ne y$ is false for every $y$ because there is no $y$ such that $x \ne y$, and thus the conjunction $x≠y∧M(x,y)$ is false while the conditional $x≠y⟹M(x,y)$ is true (conditional with false antecedent).

Comment: There is another problem besides the one that **Mauro** pointed out. Your answer implies that there is a student who is not equal to himself. Specifically, your version implies the statement $\exists x\,\forall y\,(x\ne y)$, which is plainly false.